# Не уверен в мощности JSON

Tags: php, java, json

На Java надо написать прогруммку, которая забьет текстовый файл инфой в формате Json. 40000 Json обьектов, в каждом примерно 1000 символов. Еще пока ничего не сделал, не уверен, что получится.

1. Получится ли забить так много текста в файл в Java?
2. Получится ли так же безболезненно распарсить его в php?

Comment: Почему JSON? Почему не XML?

Comment: @Дмитрий Гвоздь, а XML лучше?

Comment: По мне так 40000 записей XML легче парсить если заюзать SAX

Comment: Не знаю, что такое "забить в файл", но Вы что, сомневаетесь в возможности написать файл размером 40 Мегабайт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В случае, когда надо писать большие данные, есть одно правило - не держать их в памяти. То есть после того, как объект создан, его необходимо сразу же записать в файл. Тут никаких сложностей возникнуть не должно.

С парсингом чуть сложнее. Обычно, для разбора больших структурированных данных используются потоковые парсеры. Если коротко - парсер идет по файлу и генерирует события, которые как то обрабатываются. В Java есть `SAX` для разбора больших `XML` документов. Для `JSON` есть [`Json Simple`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/). Для реализации на PHP можете попробовать [`JSONParser`](https://github.com/kuma-giyomu/JSONParser), который работает примерно так же.

Comment: Но только несчастные 40 тысяч объектов я бы не назвал _большими данными_.

Comment: Ну это сегодня их 40 тысяч, а завтра 400, а потом и миллион... ИМХО, даже объект размером > 40 мб. может создать потенциальные проблемы, и лучше такого избегать. Если не нужен какой-то лютый перфоманс, конечно.

Comment: Ну, а послепослезавтра объём данных не помещается на жёсткий диск, и нужно строить распределённую систему :-P

Comment: Вот так и приходят к hazelcast :)

Comment: Кстати, у нас тут на сайте есть один из разработчиков hazelCast :)

Comment: @МаксимГурин почему не mongo и Cassandra?

Comment: Да я просто сказал первое, что в голову пришло)